# how to rewrite a url and change it from database values in django

Tags: python, django, neo4j, neo4django

I have two type of urls in my project:one is something like `domain.com/firstname.lastname` and another `domain.com/user_id` i like to rewrite the second url to first scheme:

```
domain.com/13243   ====>  domain.com/peter.norvig    ====>13243 is read from database
```

this is the section of my urls.py file:

```
url(r'^(?P<first_name>\w+).(?P<last_name>\w+)(.)?(?P<queueNumber>\d+)?/$',views.nameDetailIndex, name="FLSocial"),


url(r'^(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', views.idDetailIndex, name="IDSocial")
```

i want that when some one write url like `domain.com/13243` and press enter, django automatically find the `user_id` in the db and find `firstname` and `lastname` and redirect the url to domain.com/peter.norvig
i am also use neo4django db in my project

here is my views.py file:

```
def nameDetailIndex(request, first_name, last_name, queueNumber=None):
    try:
        user = User.objects.filter(firstName=first_name, lastName=last_name)
        if user:
            if not queueNumber:
                if len(user) > 1:
                    user = user[0]
            else:
                #start id counter from 1 not 0 because style of URL :D

                user = user[int(queueNumber)-1]
        else:
            raise Http404
        return render(request, 'social/public.html', {
            'user': user
        })
    except:
        raise Http404


def idDetailIndex(request, user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    return render(request, 'social/public.html', {
       'user': user
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use Http Redirect. Here's an example:

```
def idDetailIndex(request, user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    return redirect('FLSocial', first_name=user.firstName, last_name=user.lastName)
```

Comment: what should import for use `redirect` ?

Comment: `from django.shortcuts import redirect`

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an `HttpResponseRedirect`, instead of rendering a template.

After you find the `user`:

```
first = user.first_name
last = user.last_name
return HttpResponseRedirect('/%s.%s/', %(first, last))
```